# Android test project is crashing with error "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'"

Tags: android, automation, robotium

My problem seems little different than here [Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.' when testing multiple Android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891382/test-run-failed-instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-process-crashed-when-testi)

I have followed steps given [in the pdf](https://robotium.googlecode.com/files/TestAndroidCalculatorAPK-BlackBoxTesting-V1_0.pdf). I have created test project "TestAndroidCalculatorBlackbox" (do we need to have two project one test and one main project, perhaps this could be the reason, cause in Robotium "Getting Started" link they want us to create projects for Notepad), 
and added jars `robotium-solo-5.0.1.jar`,`robotium-solo-1.6.0.jar`, to get rid of red error lines below `solo.` functions and `jay.way package`.

I am attaching the error screenshot:
[image: Project tree and error screen shot]
**y AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testcalculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.testcalculator" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I have package added in instrumentation list:

```
 c:\> adb shell pm list instrumentation
instrumentation:PACKAGE.test.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=PACKAGE)
instrumentation:PACKAGE.test.test.test.test.test.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=PACKAGE.test.test)
instrumentation:com.example.android.apis/.app.LocalSampleInstrumentation (target=com.example.android.apis)
>> instrumentation:com.testcalculator/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=com.testcalculator) <<
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Don't attach more than one robotium library. robotium-solo-1.6.0.jar should be removed. It's deprecated and you really shouldn't use it anymore.
2. Is your target application already installed? It should be installed, if you are going to run tests for it. You can not install it only if your test project has reference to target project.
3. If you have separate APKs for application and instrumentation you should change package in your manifest. You actually have "com.testcalculator" and target package is the same - they should be different. By the way I don't see sources of application in your project, so application part should be removed.
4. Your error doesn't say much, it's always good to post stacktrace from LogCat.
5. Read manuals before you start writing tests:

   http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html
   https://code.google.com/p/robotium/w/list

Comment: Awesome, up-voted!!, I have commented the application part in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I see the calculator application launched but doesn't execute the test, due to error `Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'`. Perhaps the `LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.calculator.Main"` is wrong. But I don't know what it should be (I have removed `application project` and application tag from `AndroidManifest.xml` )

Comment: What class is not found? Use LogCat

Comment: My LogCat doesn't print anything

Answer (score 67):

For those migrating to or currently using `Androidx`, this error results from using 
`testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` instead of `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`.

Using the latter resolves the error completely.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your comment. Worked for me!

Comment: Yesterday I left the office thinking about this problem. And today in the morning you have solved for me!! Thank you very much Rowland!

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Android really should have clearer errors for that! Just lost an hour of work before I found your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem and fixed it by setting up `AndroidJUnitRunner` https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html

Answer (score 0):

For the developer who hasn't used androidx yet. Seeing the **LogCat** solved the issue for me which was deleting these line running in the wrong thread because of RxJava.

```
companion object {
    @get:ClassRule @JvmStatic
    val testSchedulerRule = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a StrictMode policy violation caused by AndroidJUnitRunner:

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.UntaggedSocketViolation: [...]
W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
```

Disabling the check detectUntaggedSockets() when running an Espresso test fixed it for me. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550370/how-to-detect-whether-android-app-is-running-ui-test-with-espresso) for how to check for that.